# how to display sum of the total positive integers from the user and stopping once a negative integer has been entered?

Tags: python

So my code keeps displaying the sum of the numbers 10 times instead of once. I'm trying to have the user input as many as they wan't, but I need it to stop once a negative integer has been imputed. Once that happens it's supposed to stop letting the user add numbers and display the total sum of positive numbers only. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I'm fairly new to programming and I'm stuck.

```
max = 10
total = 0.0
positive_num = 0

for counter in range (max):
    while positive_num > -1: 
        total = total + positive_num
        positive_num = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    else:
        print('Total of positive numbers is:', total)
```

Comment: Why not just omit the `else` and simply write the print after the loop?

Comment: I feel dumb, thanks! I guess i was overthinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop isn't letting the user input as many as they want, it's only inputting a max of 10 numbers, you should change it to an infinite loop with a break on negative input:

```
total = 0.0

while True:
    positive_num = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    if positive_num > -1:
        total = total + positive_num
    else:
        print('Total of positive numbers is:', total)
        break
```